# multiplying floating point numbers produces zero

Tags: ruby

the code below outputs 0.0. is this because of the overflow? how to avoid it? if not, why?

```
p ((1..100000).map {rand}).reduce :*
```

I was hoping to speed up this code:

```
p r.reduce(0) {|m, v| m + (Math.log10 v)}
```

and use this instead:

```
p Math.log10 (r.reduce :*)
```

but apparently this is not always possible...

Comment: r is a set of numbers each having the integer part 9 digits long, so I am getting Infinity as the product... and if I convert them to integers, then product takes forever to calculate.

Comment: What is the goal of the calculation? You just want some number composited of the others?

Comment: I need to calculate the sum of the logarithms or the logarithm of the product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values produced by rand are all between 0.0 and 1.0. This means that on each multiplication, your number gets smaller. So by the time you have multiplied 1000 of them, it is probably indistinguishable from 0.

At some point, ruby will take your number to be so small that it is 0. for instance: `2.0e-1000 # => 0`

Comment: makes sense thanks. I have edited my question, explaining why I was doing that.

Comment: +1. With a range of (0..730) the product is varying between ~ 10E-300 and 0.

Comment: The problem with floating point numbers is that they are a digital medium to describe a continuous space, it is fundamentally impossible to accurately store all numbers in a digital computer with finite memory. There are limits to storage size and therefore accuracy

Comment: Good answer, except for the example of "100".  While the number is close to zero after 100 multiplications, it almost certainly (depending on `#rand`) hasn't underflowed at all. At that point it's only about `10**-50` and so the entire 52-bit mantissa still contains accurate bits.  But at around 700 ops, then, it's going to underflow.

Comment: The number 100 came from this example, which is multiplying only the *smallest* values from the 100,000 rand calls. `(1..100000).map {rand}.sort[0..100].reduce(&:*)` I'll fix that above.

Answer (score 1):

Every multiplication reduces your number by about **1/2<sup>1</sup>**, so after about 50 of them, you are down **1/2<sup>50</sup>,** and after 100000 (actually, after about 700) you have *[underflowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underflow)* the [FP format itself, see here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby provides the [`BigDecimal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) class, which implements accurate floating point arithmetic.

```
require 'bigdecimal'

n = 100

decimals = n.times.map { BigDecimal.new rand.to_s }
result = decimals.reduce :*

result.nonzero?.nil?  # returns nil if zero, self otherwise
# => false

result.precs  # [significant_digits, maximum_significant_digits]
# => [1575, 1764]

Math.log10 result
# => -46.8031931083014
```

It is a lot slower than native floating point numbers, however. With `n = 100_000`, the `decimals.reduce :*` call went on for minutes on my computer before I finally interrupted it.